# ASP.NET MVC Controller extension method to make Log available to all controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

Is it possible to extend the Controller type in Asp.net MVC to make a method available to all controller classes for application logging?
I've tried this:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        public static ILog Log(this Controller controller)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            return log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(controller.GetType());
        }
    }
```

But, if I try to access the method as in:

```
Controller.Log.Info("hello");
```

It won't compile with the error message: *'System.Web.Mvc.Controller' does not contain a definition for 'Log'*

I do have a using statement bringing the static class into scope.

Any help would be great.
Jacques

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest to implement abstract base controller class for this purpose:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ILog Log
    {
        get { return LogManager.GetLogger(GetType()); }
    }
}
```

You can also achieve similar result using `protected static` log instance, here is an example with `Serilog`:

```
protected static readonly ILogger log = Log.ForContext(typeof(MyController));
```

Comment: I used this approach in the end. Thanks Andrei

Comment: I like this approach.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
//inside a controller's method
this.Log().Info("hello");
```

You're not adding a property `Log`, you're adding an extension method `Log()`.

There's no such thing as "extension properties".

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a custom action filter?

**create a class LogInfo inherited by ActionFilterattribute**

```
public class LogInfo : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           //Logging operation code here
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[LogInfo]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: I used @Andrei's approach, but I'm interested in your answer. For this filter, how would I go about setting specific log conditions if it weren't just a standard info log. For example if an exception occurred inside the Index method, could I use the filter to log an exception?